# remote call javascript function from another site

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, remote-access

I have a upload script in another host and after remote file upload with `Ajax` I call a function like this :

```
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopUpload('.$result.' , \'res2\' , uploaded , dkey);</script>';
```

the `stopUpload` function in the main page should run and do some thing (show pictures and ...)
but I get Permission denied error

```
Error: Permission denied to access property "stopUpload"
```

**tip :** Imagine I have `stopUpload` function in `pageA` and I call send file with ajax to upload in my another Host page called `pageB` I have a `stopUpload` function in pageB which should run on pageA after upload complete but face to above error ...

Can I call javascript function in another page remotely?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like "cross-site scripting" Google it!

Comment: @John Hartsock is this works like XSS ?

Comment: rephrase....I have no idea what your asking?

Comment: @JohnHartsock Well , I think it is clear but see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably violating [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

An `Iframe` can access parent window content only if they both belong to same origin.
An origin consists of `Protocol (http/https)`, `domain name(example.com` and `port(default 80)`. If any of these are different then sites are considered from different origins. If you are able to modify content of both the sites then you can manually set the `document.domain=domain.com`. After that you won't get the error.

***#Edit***

Both the sites should at least have super domain in common for manual domain setting to work.

For example, `facebook.com and google.com can never be compatible` since their super domains are different.

However `docs.google.com and developer.google.com can be compatible` as they have `super domain google.com` in common.

They both would have to declare `document.domain=google.com` in a script tag.

Comment: Thanks , I should add document.domain in this host page which stopUpload function exist?

Comment: Welcome, it should be added to both the sites.

Comment: Excuse me But In pageA I should add pageB domain and in pageB should add pageA domain , yes?

Comment: `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_DOCUMENT_DOMAIN: Illegal document.domain value` this error occured after adding that

Comment: what value are you setting ?

Comment: document.domain = 'citygramcdn.ir'; pageA

Comment: Both the sites should have at least super domain in common.

Comment: `document.domain = 'citygramcdn.ir';` in pageA
`document.domain = 'citygram.ir';` in pageB
And that error in on pageA